# Number of bins in matplotlib axes (number of majorticks)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have 6 axes in one figure. The limits on each axes are different. On each axes I gave the command:

```
ax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=9)
ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=7)
```

But when I plot this I get:

[image]

I want to get 9 majorticks with 9 labels on the x axis of each axes, and 7 on the y axis of each axes. How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please share the full code of plot.

Comment: you can use matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator to do what you want. If you can share the plot code. I can give the answer with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
# add plot code here
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=9))
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=7))
#repeat for other axes
```